# Opencart Injection Attack

Tags: php, opencart, code-injection, opencart2.x

i found this error on my opencar's log ( error.log )

> 2017-04-11 13:42:45 - PHP Warning:  is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be
>   a valid path, string given in
>   /home/xxxx/domains/xxxx.com/public_html/system/modification/system/engine/action.php
>   on line 172017-04-11 13:42:45 - PHP Warning:  is_file() expects
>   parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in
>   /home/xxxx/domains/xxx.com/public_html/system/modification/system/engine/action.php
>   on line 27

I dont know how to prevent it, but when i see the code like this :

```
$file = DIR_APPLICATION . 'controller/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $path) . '.php';
if (is_file($file)) {
    $this->file = $file;

    $this->class = 'Controller' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $path);

    array_shift($parts);

    break;
}
```

i feel someone inject the ftp path, so opencart return the error.

can someone tell me how to prevent it ???

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling a Controller like this? You are able to easily load in Controllers with the framework of OpenCart, this makes you able to load in contents of your website through custom controllers, this about a header or footer.

**Example in a controller:**

```
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
```

Above the $data variable is the variable whitch is send with setting the output (view). You are able to echo it in the view as '$header'.

**Example of echoing:**

```
<?=$header?>
```

Comment: thats not what i mean...

my code describe a snippet from action.php on my opencart system code..